# How to let Spring Boot configure RabbitMQ configuration based on externalised config?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-boot

I am trying to find ways to declare queues etc in a way that they are automatically created when the applications starts up. I know that this can be done by adding the creation of the queues via Java code but ideally it would be nice if Spring Boot would configure my RabbitMQ environment based on an xml configuration. I tried creating a resources.xml file with no luck so far. So i am wondering if this is even possible?

Any hints on how to proceed or some example how this could be done?

Comment: Please be more specific about what particularly you're trying to set up. Spring Boot (and/or Spring Cloud Connectors) will set up your connection to the broker, and attaching to specific endpoints is generally something that you'd do with something like Spring Integration.

Comment: In a precious project done with Grails i was able to define the queues etc in an external file and if they would not exist then they would be created without having to deal with them in code.

Also the binding queues with exchange could be done by just configuring them. Examples are here: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-rabbitmq/docs/manual/guide/configuration.html 

So i was wondering if this also can be done in Spring Boot, but maybe indeed i have to add Spring Integration which is new to me.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you were doing with Grails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow to Spring AMQP to populate AMQP object on application startup you must declare them as beans and use `<rabbit:>` namespace for XML configuration to simplify your life.

Somethis like this:

```
<rabbit:queue name="my.queue" />

<rabbit:direct-exchange name="my.exchange">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="my.queue" key="my.routingKey" />
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:direct-exchange>
```

When you have that config in the `resources.xml`, you will be able to `import` it to the main Boot config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource("classpath:com/my/proj/configs/resources.xml")
public class MyConfiguration {
}
```

Thanks to Spring Boot Autoconfiguration, it produces `RabbitAdmin` bean for us to populate those AMQP objects on start up.

Comment: Just to be clear, i have to create the queues and exchanges manually using the rabbitAdmin bean?

Comment: No, `RabitAdmin` bean does it for you: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#automatic-declaration

Comment: @ArtemBilan along similar lines, how can I configure host, port, etc. with just an application.yml (instead of resource XML file)? Thanks.

Comment: See this one http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html with `RABBIT` comment.